# Accessing a property inside a function defined in a method in PHP

Tags: php, oop, methods, private

I need to call a function inside a method. This function needs access to a private property. This code:

```
class tc {
  private $data=123;

  public function test() {
    function test2() {
      echo $this->data;
    }

    test2();
  }
}

$a=new tc();
$a->test();
```

returns the following error:

**Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in ... on line ...**

Using PHP 5.6.38. How can I do this?

Comment: Because test2 is a function within the test method, not a method in the tc object. You're not in the object scope.

Comment: And the property is private, which means you can't access outside the object.

Comment: Still, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Why don't you make `test2` a real method instead of nesting it?

Comment: test2 is included from another file.

Comment: Note that functions nested inside a class method are NOT executed in class scope. So there's not much point in using nested functions like this.

Comment: My use case is to include different files that contain different test2 functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why would you declare a function inside a method, but if that is what you want to do, then pass the private member as a parameter to this function.

```
<?php 

class tc {
  private $data=123;

  public function test() {
    function test2($data) {
        echo $data;
    }

    test2($this->data);
  }

}

$a=new tc();
$a->test();
```

Comment: This seems to be the answer.

Comment: @dj50 glad to help.